# The console has been disconnected. Close this window and re-launch the console to reconnect

Tags: virtual-machine, vsphere, esxi

I am having an issue when trying to open to any VMs using "Launch Web Console" option  via the vcsa 6.7 . I was wondering if someone could please point me in the right direction?

My environment currently looks like this:
1) vcsa 6.7
2) Three Esxi (6.7) Hosts & multiple vms are running (including windows & Linux)

Whenever I try to connect to the console, I get the following error:

The console has been disconnected. Close this window and re-launch the console to reconnect.
[image: screenshot with an error quoted above]

Comment: Need your input how to solve this issue

Comment: It gets resolved by Disconnecting & then connecting Esxi Host

Answer (score 0):

Console access is given through a connection to the ESXi host.

Often times I receive this message when connected to the console of a VM which has vMotioned to another host. However, I can close and re-open the console just fine.

You may also want to verify that you can access port 902 (TCP & UDP) for each of your three hosts. Example of this requirement: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc/GUID-5071C86E-FF1E-4E54-A424-A20917401160.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and unfortunately, the solutions I found on the internet did not solve my problem. I had to re-check my settings and found out that the problem was the proxy setting was ticked on. which it won't allow you to connect to any others services as well if you are out of range of that proxy. The Solutions "FOR MAC USERS" as follows:

1-Go to your network settings.

2-From the menu down to the right-click more options. in my picture say (Weitere Optionen) "German".

3-From the menu on the left side make sure that the proxy option is 'unticked' (not chosen).

Then click on to confirm and enjoy using your VM service. Hope this would solve your problem as well as it did to mine.

See pictures!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PjjP.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jnJf.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XiAY.jpg